# On the greatest integer that cannot be expressed as $c_{1}a_{1}+c_{2}a_{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $G(a_{1},a_{2})$ be the greatest integer that can not be expressed as $c_{1}a_{1}+c_{2}a_{2}$, where $a_{i}$'s are relatively prime natural numbers, and $c_{i}$ is a whole number.

---

> Formula: $G(a_{1},a_{2})=a_{1}a_{2}-(a_{1}+a_{2})$.

---

- Example: $G(8,3)=8\times3-(8+3)=24-11=13$.

$14$ can be expressed as $1(8)+2(3)$, $15$ can be expressed as $0(8)+5(3)$, $16$ can be expressed as $2(8)+0(3)$, $17$ can be expressed as $1(8)+3(3)$, $18$ can be expressed as $0(8)+6(3)$, $19$ can be expressed as $2(8)+1(3)$, and so on, and all natural numbers after $13$ can be expressed as $c_{1}(8)+c_{2}(3)$ for some whole numbers $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$.

---

> Do we have a formula for $G(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3})$?

That is the greatest integer the can not be expressed as $c_{1}a_1+c_{2}a_{2}+c_{3}a_{3}$, where $a_{i}$'s are relatively prime natural number, and $c_{i}$ is a whole number.

Am I right that $G(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3})=G(G(a_{1},a_{2}),a_{3})=G(a_{1}a_{2}-(a_{1}+a_{2}),a_{3})$?

---

> How can we prove that $G(a_{1},a_{2})=a_{1}a_{2}-(a_{1}+a_{2})$?

Comment: Note that there is no such greatest integer if $\gcd(a_1,a_2)\neq1$, and so your formula cannot be right.

Comment: I suspect $c_i$ are supposed to be *nonnegative*. Look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem).

Comment: Moreover, in your example; the whole numbers $c_1=2$ and $c_2=-1$ yield
$$c_1a_1+c_2a_2=2\times8+(-1)\times3=13.$$
Do you mean that $c_1$ and $c_2$ should also be *natural* numbers?

Comment: @Servaes whole number are the non-negative integers.

Comment: @metamorphy yes, nonnegative integers are the whole numbers.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari No, the whole numbers are the integers. The natural numbers are either the positive or the non-negative integers, depending on who you ask. For this question, the distinction does not matter.

Comment: @Servaes ok dear whatever, what I mean here $c_{i}$'s are non negative integers. See the link: https://www.mathsisfun.com/whole-numbers.html

Comment: aka $(a_1-1)(a_2-1)-1$

Comment: Sure, [links don't mean much](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_number). Anyway, what about the first problem, if $\gcd(a_1,a_2)\neq1$?

Comment: @Servaes I already edited my post, I said $a_{i}$'s are relatively prime.

Answer (score 2):

Good question (it is in my interest) anyway the Problem is the Frobenius or coin problem, there are plenty of proofs for your first formula. As for $3$ coprime generators, it gets complicated and it is not true where you said am i right since when you add a generator $a_3$ to $(a_1,a_2)$ which are coprime your number $G$ will get smaller.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that I was wrong. I will check  the Frobenius or coin problem.